# Get dynamic sql in Golang

Tags: rest, go

I am trying to create a REST API in Golang. The problem is that I have more than 1000 complex SQL script that should be executed and fetched from the database.

Is it possible to take the web address *`/get/job/23`* and dynamically grab the sql from a package, template or text document that basically contain text only = sql script? And then fire the prepare and execute in the ***main.go***?

It seems that importing 1000 packages and storing 1000 complex SQL statements in the ***main.go*** is sort of impossible.

Here is a newbie pseudo code that shows what I am looking for:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "log"
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func Getsql (dynamic path to script with parameter) returns (string)      

/* The url /get/job/id is stored as a document/package/template       
as "getjobid" = dynamic path based on url passed */

func (db *DB) Conn(ctx context.Context) (*Conn, error)
func (db *DB) Prepare(query string) (*Stmt, error)
func (db *DB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*Rows, err)

func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Of course, I do not know if this is even possible, but I am thankful for pointing me in the right direction.

**Added**

I think of this as 4 problem to solve:

1. How to store the plain sql in a document (template?) within Golang
2. How to dynamically set the path to this document based on url.
3. How to send parameters to a document (id)
4. How to read the content and execute the sql

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend finding a design pattern that you like and building around that. For example, you can use `MVC`, or `Clean Architecture`, etc.

A simple way to do what you want in `MVC` is to create controllers that map to each path, and the controller can access a specific database repository function, and that specific database repository function can have your SQL in it.

This will give you a nice separation of concerns. You don't want to end up having 1000 different SQL queries and 1000 request handlers in the same file, that won't be maintainable. With `MVC` you can abstract this logic away to decouple things.

But even `MVC` will have its limitations after a while once you start having directories with 1000 files, etc. However, I think it's a really good start for your use case since you just want REST endpoints mapped to a request handler, which then queries the database.

Here is an example (note that I left a bunch of links for your reference at the bottom).

**main.go:**

```
package main

import (
   "log"
    "net/http"

    "controllers"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", controllers.Index)
    http.HandleFunc("/users", controllers.AllUsers)
    http.HandleFunc("/users/:id", controllers.OneUser)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

**controllers.go:**

```
import "repository"

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Home page")
}

func AllUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    users := repository.AllUsers()

    h.Write([]byte(users))
}

func OneUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := repository.OneUser(r.Param("id"))

    h.Write([]byte(user))
}
```

**repository.go:**

```
func AllUsers() []User {
    var users []User
    db.Select(&users, `SELECT * FROM user`)
    return users
}

func OneUser(userId int) *User {
    user := new(User)
    db.Get(user, `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?`, userId)
    return user
}
```

Bear in mind that this is a very simplistic answer that uses code that won't compile, doesn't handle errors, etc. But it should give you a general idea of how you can build an architecture to achieve what you want.

Hope that helps!

Here are some resources you might find helpful in building a RESTful API in Golang:

- https://www.codementor.io/codehakase/building-a-restful-api-with-golang-a6yivzqdo
- https://thenewstack.io/make-a-restful-json-api-go/
- https://hackernoon.com/build-restful-api-in-go-and-mongodb-5e7f2ec4be94

Here are some routers for REST API's:

- https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin
- https://github.com/go-chi/chi
- https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter

Here are some database packages to help make your SQL queries simple:

- https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx

Comment: Where is the dynamic part? To hardcode 1000 paths is "simple" but lots of typing :-)

Comment: Ah your question was slightly vague, by dynamically I thought you meant like a specific path can be routed to a specific SQL function (which is exactly what my example does). To achieve this I think you will have to create some kind of custom pattern within your app to map a path to a specific SQL file by prefix or something like that. Ex: `/user/:id` -> `/database/user/by-id.sql`

Comment: Yes, I was vague, because I do not know how to ask. Dynamic for me is that you save a lot of typing by using parameters created by the url and pointing to a document with same name as the parameter. Any idea how to save typing?

Comment: I would recommend against this. The only conceivable trivial way to get this done is by either implementing some kind of hash table, or using regexp. Regexp to find files within your system is probably a very bad idea and vulnerable to security issues. Hash table might be a solution, but still requires hardcoding some mappings, which strays from the whole "completely dynamic" philosophy. Nonetheless I will think of something and get back to you.